# copy/paste module from another project to new project in laravel but getting 404

Tags: laravel, module, routes, laravel-6, laravel-modules

I've already wrote a module and need this module in my new project, so I copied it into the new project, but I get 404 error for every route of this module that i copied ,im using laravel v6.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i've just copy the folder of module that i need(Filemanager)  and pasted into the Modules folder of laravel , but the route of Filemanager (as example filemanager.index return 404 , ive used resource route by the way)

Answer (score 0):

i've just solved this problem :
the name of old module was **Filemanager** so:

1. first i deleted Filemanager module from the new project/Modules
2. make the same module with artisan command(Exactly the same name(Filemanager)):

   **php artisan module:make Filemanager**
3. then removed all the folders except:

   composer.json,module.json,package.json,webpack.mix.js

### and replace it with folders of old module(old filemanagers folders)

ps: i've just shared this answer for those who have same problem as me,
but still looking for real,quick and
Reasonable answer.